# MiKTeX can't find fkob.cfg

Tags: errors, miktex, kpfonts

I'm trying to compile this document. 
I am using Winedt 7, MiKTeX under Windows 7 pro 64 bits.
This is the message I get the error below.

------ LaTeX document --------------------------------------------------------

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{fko}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\newfont{\chapfont}{fkob8t at 3cm}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{50pt}%
  {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
   \raggedright
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \value{secnumdepth} >-1
      \if@mainmatter
         {\chapfont\thechapter}%
            \hspace*{1em}%
      \fi
   \fi
    \Huge\bfseries #1\par\nobreak
   \vspace{40pt}
   }
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
   \fancyhf{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\fancypagestyle{perso}{%
   \fancyhf{} % tous les paramètres actuels sont effacés
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\small\thepage}
   \fancyhead[RE]{\small\itshape\leftmark}
   \fancyhead[LO]{\small\itshape\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{perso}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
   \markboth{Chapitre \thechapter\ -- #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
   \markright{\thesection\ -- #1}}

\renewcommand{\thepart}{%
   \ifcase\value{part}
   \or Premi\`ere\or Deuxi\`eme\or Troisi\`eme\or Quatri\`eme
   \or Cinqui\`eme\or Sixi\`eme\or Septi\`eme\or Huiti\`eme
   \or Neuvi\`eme\or Dixi\`eme\or Onzi\`eme\or Douzi\`eme
   \or Treizi\`eme\or Quatorzi\`eme\or Quinzi\`eme\or Seizi\`eme
   \or Dix-septi\`eme\or Dix-huiti\`eme\or Dix-neuvi\`eme\or Vingti\`eme
   \fi\space partie
}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapitre~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\leavevmode\cleaders\hbox to 1em {\hfil.\hfil}\hfill}
\settowidth{\cftchapnumwidth}{\cftchapfont Chapitre~XVIII}
\settowidth{\cftsecnumwidth}{\cftsecfont XVIII.99}
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\par\nobreak\hrulefill}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Un}

La Loi est l'expression de la volonté générale. Tous les Citoyens ont droit
de concourir personnellement, ou par leurs Représentants, à sa formation.
Elle doit être la même pour tous, soit qu'elle protège, soit qu'elle
punisse. Tous les Citoyens étant égaux à ses yeux sont également
admissibles à toutes dignités, places et emplois publics, selon leur
capacité, et sans autre distinction que celle de leurs vertus et de leurs talents.

Hi evry one
\end{document}
```

----Error : ---------------------------------------------------------------

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\frenchb.cfg")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\carlisle\scalefnt.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The fkob8t source file could not be found.

Running hbf2gf.exe...

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0)

Couldn't find `fkob.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font fkob8t.

! Font \chapfont=fkob8t at 85.35826pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.10 \newfont{\chapfont}{fkob8t at 3cm}

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on modifybook.log.
texify: pdflatex.exe failed for some reason (see log file).
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It seems that font is not installed by default with miktex.

Comment: What font should `fkob8t` be? A search on CTAN gave no result.

Comment: Can you please name the font you want to use? I found no definition of font `fko` following the Karl Berry scheme ...

Comment: Since you tagged it with [tag:kpfonts]: You must use the right low level name for the roman font. The most simple would be `jkp`, but see the documentation for all variants.

Comment: See also [\newfont command not working; which fonts can I substitute?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16108/newfont-command-not-working-which-fonts-can-i-substitute). You should use something like `\newcommand*{\chapfont}{\fontfamily{jkp}\fontsize{3cm}{3.5cm}\linespread{1.1}\selectfont}`.